# Check if process is done in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, process

We have this process and we want to know if the process is done? How we'll be able to check if it is done?

Here is the code:

```
Process.Start(filePath & ".bat", filePath.Substring(0, filePath.LastIndexOf("\")))
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several properties/methods you can use after you have saved the return value of Process.Start to a variable:

- If you want to wait until the Process has exited, use the [WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.
- If you want to check whether the Process is still running, use the [HasExited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.
- If you need the exit code after the Process has ended, use the [ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

For an overview of the Process class and its capabilities, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Sample:

```
Dim p As Process = Process.Start(filePath & ".bat", filePath.Substring(0, filePath.LastIndexOf("\")))
p.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: i'll declare P as what ?