# how to show msgbox if any process is closed

Tags: vb.net

This is my code, it works only on form load or click.

But I need to show this msgbox when process close while my app running.

```
Dim p() As Process
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        ' Process is running
        MsgBox("Running!")
    Else
        ' Process is not running
        MsgBox("Not running!")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to monitor the status->Running or status->NotRunning of a process, 
**while** your Application is executing.
This requires a method that *continuously* updates the Status of a monitored foreign process.

How this method works, depends on you application functionality:

- Is invisible and becomes visible/operable when the monitored process
  starts?
- Operates indipendently from this foreign process, but takes special
  actions when this other process becomes active?
- Executes visible and its only purpose is to monitor the foreign
  process?
- Other

  First take a look to:
  [Check if process is done in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345195/check-if-process-is-done-in-vb-net)
  [application closes itself when another program closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710978/application-closes-itself-when-another-program-closes)
  [Wait for a specefic program to open before continue VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554162/wait-for-a-specefic-program-to-open-before-continue-vb-net)

I suggest you learn how to instantiate a [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.1).
It's a very straightforward and helpful tool to use if you don't want to *manually* control an
 Asynchronous task.

A BackgroundWorker can be *instructed* to notify your main process (application) that a defined condition has changed.
When this condition is met, the BW raises an Event, letting you know what happend or changed.
Then you decide how to proceed, or - if it is the case - you can terminate the activity of the BackgroundWorker.
Give it a try.